# Is there a CSS selector for the disjunction of :nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+4)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say that I want the 2nd, 3rd and 4th of a list item to be red, and the rest to be blue. One way I know of doing that is

```
<ul class="some-list">
    <li>Here's a list item</li> 
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li> 
    <li>Here's a list item</li> 
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li> 
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
    <li>Here's a list item</li>    
</ul>
```

---

```
ul.some-list {}
ul.some-list > li { color: blue;}
ul.some-list > li:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+4) { color: red;}
```

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bkfyg27/

---

However, I don't like that solution. I don't think it's elegant because it relies on overriding properties. It would be better if I had something that was the opposite of `:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+4)`.

In general, I'm wondering if there's a CSS way of selecting the mathematical disjunction of `nth-of-type` selectors for `n` in the range `[a, b]`? That is, a way of doing

```
{1, 2, 3, ... } \ {a, a + 1, ..., b}
```

Comment: maybe you man the selector is not easily readable such as, but it works and is efficient.

Comment: @GCyrillus I never compromise readability, efficiency, reliably and cleverness. I maximize all.

Comment: Note that CSS means "Cascading Style Sheets". And that "cascade" means that "if more than one rule matches against a particular element, priorities or weights are calculated and assigned to rules, so that the results are predictable" (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)). So maybe you don't think it's elegant, but the language is designed like this.

Comment: I think I'd use a simple selector list rather than all that `of-type` rigmarole. But then again I love to maximize elegant, clever compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) to negate.

```css
ul.some-list > li:not(:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+4)) {
    color: blue;
}
```

The problem is that the code above won't work, because in Selectors Level 3, `:not()` only accepts [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn), but two pseudo-class selectors are a [sequence of simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sequence-of-simple-selectors). That might change in Selectors Level 4, tough.

To fix that, separate them into different selectors:

```css
ul.some-list > li:not(:nth-of-type(n+2)),
ul.some-list > li:not(:nth-of-type(-n+4)) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```css
ul.some-list > li:not(:nth-of-type(n+2)),
ul.some-list > li:not(:nth-of-type(-n+4)) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
</ul>
```

But then `:not()` is no longer useful, because the following is simpler:

```css
ul.some-list > li:nth-of-type(-n+1),
ul.some-list > li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
ul.some-list > li:nth-of-type(-n+1),
ul.some-list > li:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="some-list">
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
  <li>Here's a list item</li>
</ul>
```